# It seems like Jenkins pipeline is unable to access the GitHub repository, although in reality, it can

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

The issue with deploying a Jenkins pipeline specifically shows the following error: `fatal: unable to access "GitHubrepo" GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.` Even though access to this repository is granted via a token that is appropriately configured, how can this problem be resolved?

I have checked the access to GitHub on the server, and everything is accessible, but only when I insert the token along with the repository link in the Git.